# How to prevent my RabbitMQ pod from autoscaling and restarting

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, rabbitmq, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: staging
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: rabbitmq
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: bitnami
        namespace: kube-system
      version: "8.22.3"
  interval: 5m
  releaseName: rabbitmq
  values:
    priorityClassName: system-node-critical
    replicaCount: 4
    auth:
        username: staging
        password: rabbitmq-secret
        existingPasswordSecret: rabbitmq-secret
        erlangCookie: **************************
    extraConfiguration: |-
      default_vhost=use2-mmc-1021
      consumer_timeout=86400000
    memoryHighWatermark:
        enabled: "true"
        type: absolute
        value: 1536MB
    resources:
        limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2048Mi
        requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2048Mi
    livenessProbe:
        initialDelaySeconds: 120
        timeoutSeconds: 20
        periodSeconds: 30
        failureThreshold: 6
        successThreshold: 1
    readinessProbe:
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        timeoutSeconds: 20
        periodSeconds: 30
        failureThreshold: 3
        successThreshold: 1
    service:
        type: ClusterIP
    serviceAccount:
        create: true
```

This is my code for rabbitmq.yaml file.
I want to prevent my pod from restarting , as restarting the pod takes some time which results in server errors.
cluster autoscaler should not affect my rabbitmq pod.
i've already tried using `system-node-critical` in my code , it didn't make any difference.
please help me out with some answers to my problem.
cluster autoscaler should not affect my rabbitmq pod or how to make my pod as System-node-critical.

Comment: Would appreciate seeing some logs to give you an educated advise.

Comment: We have the same issue and I wonder if rabbit should work properly  on kubernetes. Every time the auto scale works shutdown a rabbit node and disconnect the application